# Replacing "/" with ":" using jQuery

Tags: javascript

New to jQuery & JavaScript.

I have

```
var x = location.pathname;
```

(ex: /abc/collection/tea/green/index.php)

Like this I have various pathname retrieved using `location.pathname`.

I want to replace all "/" in the pathname with ":" (I mean a / with a :) and also I don't want the .php which is at the end. Any help please.

Comment: I think you should remove jQuery as a tag as this is simply a JavaScript question.

Comment: var old_val = '/';  var new_val = old_val.replace('/',':');  alert(new_val);

Answer (score -1):

This has nothing to do with jQuery.  You can use JavaScript to replace your string.

Like this:

```
var x = location.pathname;
x = x.replace(/\//g, ":");
```

or just

```
var x = location.pathname.replace(/\//g, ":");
```

You can also use the same method to remove the ".php" by adding this:

```
x = x.replace(/\.php$/i, "");
```

(assuming you only need to replace it once at the end)

Basically you have to use the regex version of `str.replace()` and the `g` (global) switch to do a replace all. Use the `str.replace(/texthere/g, "replacement")` pattern to replace more than one occurrence - just remember to properly escape 'texthere' so characters don't conflict.

Comment: How to do it. Completely new to javaScript.

Comment: Thanks. This is working.